# Explaining source code via "doc"?

Tags: documentation, comments, phpdoc, jsdoc

I am using PHPDoc and JSDoc for my source code. I know that there are tools to build an API out of those docs. However, what I am wondering is that how is one supposed to explain complex code? Do I just use multiline comments inside functions rather than explaining in the PHPDoc/JSDoc?

For example, consider this code:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
 * @param {Integer} width
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
function setWidth(width) {
 // Very complex code goes here...
}
```

In the above case, how should I go for commenting the complex code? I do not think I can do that in the JSDoc since it is used for building an API (which is about "how to use" rather than "how things work"), right?

Are my assumptions correct:

- JSDoc/PHPDoc is solely written for those who are going to use the function/method.
- Comments within the function are written for anyone who needs to understand the logic behind the function/method.
- Documentation is separate from API and source code comments, the documentation (that every software should provide) is written for those who want to use the software.

But what I do not understand is that what explains the software in an architectural level -- should there be a developer documentation, too?

What are your strategies to perfect documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You document **Public** Interfaces with those tools, you don't want consumers of the API to know or care about the implementation details, you put those comments in the code itself. Also "perfect" documentation [is not really a good goal](http://agilemanifesto.org/). The ***BEST*** documentation is working example code that uses the Interfaces in a obvious manner. Unit tests fit this requirement nicely in most cases.

Comment: What about documenting architectural decisions?

Comment: Wiki is the best thing, because it is a live document, and those decisions usually context and discussion/commentary because sometimes they are less than optimal for good reason

Answer (score 1):

If you really feel the need to document something about the inner workings of a function, that mainly only the developers of the code need to know, phpDocumentor does have the @internal tag.

When you use the --parseprivate runtime option, non-public code elements (like private variables, protected methods, etc) become visible in your generated documenation.  Text that you include via the @internal tag also becomes visible.

It sounds to me like the descriptions that you want to write regarding the internal method code would be good candidates for such @internal usage.